# why the background_color and color are different in kivy?

Tags: kivy

I used Kiny framework as UI.

I got a really strange between color and background color

even if i set same value of `rgb(0.1, 0.9, 0.6)` but it is described different color on screen.

here is my set

```
Label:
            size_hint: 0.33, None
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
            x: root_header.x+45
            color: 0.1, 0.90, 0.60, 1
            font_size: 20
            markup: True

Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '150dp', '48dp'
            text: '70121'
            on_release: sm.current = 'default'  
            background_color: (0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 1.0)
```

Comment: but it's not the same value in your code?

Comment: Oh I put wrong code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background_color is applied as a multiplier to the Button texture colour, but the Button texture is initially grey so you end up with something darker than expected. You can instead also change the background image, e.g. to something where the main colour is white (which will be tinted as you want).